# AttributeError: __enter__ error when trying to query from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

The following used to worked for me.
For some reason it is not anymore.

```
>>> import configparser
>>> from mysql.connector import connect, Error
>>> with open('file.cfg', 'r') as f:
...     config_string = '[s]\n' + f.read()
...
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read_string(config_string)
>>> with connect(host=config.get('s','HOST'),user=config.get('s','USER'),password=config.get('s','PASS'),database="db") as connection:
...     with connection.cursor() as cursor:
...             cursor.execute("select dt from tab limit 1")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __enter__
>>>
```

mysql_connector-2.2.9-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl

Python 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution:

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
pip uninstall mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

The problem, as I see it was that I had installed `mysql-connector` (which is deprecated) after `mysql-connector-python` (new the new version of `mysql-connector`).
Thous, making `mysql-connector-python` the only lib on the box that python can use.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would give some context to your answer. Currently this is really a low quality answer.

Comment: The uninstall-install steps may have installed a new version. So, it might help future readers to know what versions are now installed that fixed your problem.

Comment: This was really helpful for me, everything was working on my machine, but when I was to build the container, I used `mysql-connector` instead of `mysql-connector-python` in the requirements file.

Comment: This was it for me.  I was using the deprecated connector.  Updated to new one and now it works!

Comment: Holy crap, it worked!  I started my virtual environment with #> source venv/bin/activate, then ran the commands above and voila, it worked!